# Actions on Google - Ask user to re link their account before token expires

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Our agent uses OAuth account linking with Authentication code. We would like to suggest to the user to relink their account when the consent they've given is about to expire.

To achieve that, we first invalidate the consent on our auth server and then proceed to respond with a `new SignIn()`. However, the agent doesn't immediately recognise that the token is invalid, so the `new SignIn()` doesn't force the user to link their account again and does nothing.

Is there a way to force the agent to do the account linking process?

Note: Returning a 401 response (`UnauthorisedError`) is not really an option because we don't want the conversation to end. Instead we want the user to continue his conversation after their account is linked.

Answer (score 1):

The platform does not have a way to perform reauthentication inline. To force the agent to perform account linking, you will need to return a 401 `UnauthorizedError` and the user will sign in again the next time they invoke the action.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @NickFleker! I was afraid this was the case but unfortunately this is not what we are looking for at this moment. Hopefully there will be alternative solutions in the future.